# Gridview update button on enter

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Is there a way to do this. Say a user is in the update row of a datagridview. They just want to hit enter and fire the update button not mater where they are on the row. Is there a way to do that? I have tried messing with the tab order but could I just leave the update label out of the tab order and just make it update when the user hits enter?

```
<%@ Assembly src="porch_samples.ascx.cs" %>
<%@ Control Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="porch_samples.ascx.cs"       Inherits="porch_samples.hendrix" TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5"  %>
<%@ Register Assembly="obout_ComboBox" Namespace="Obout.ComboBox" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
   <script type="text/javascript">



    </script>

<div style="OVERFLOW: auto; LEFT: -1px; WIDTH: 1320px; POSITION: relative;  HEIGHT: 550px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FFFFFF; top: 0px;">






<% // drop down lists %>

<asp:DropDownList ID="listQcId" style="Z-INDEX: 159; LEFT:95px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 5px;"
        runat="server" DataSourceID="fill_qc_id_grid" 
        DataTextField="qc_id" DataValueField="qc_id" 
        AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Selected ="True" Text="" Value ="">(Select)</asp:ListItem>

        </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="fill_qc_id_grid" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AADConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select distinct fta.qc_id from t_ap_qc_master_fta fta
inner join t_ap_qc_master qcm on qcm.qc_id = fta.qc_id
where
isnull(qcm.qc_complete,'N') = 'N'
and qcm.qc_type like 'Receiving'"></asp:SqlDataSource>


          <asp:GridView ID="grdPanel" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" style= "Z-INDEX: 159; LEFT:10px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 40px;" 
              CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="progress" EnableModelValidation="True" 
              Font-Size="Smaller" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
              DataKeyNames="qc_id,Smpl_ID">
              <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
              <Columns>
                  <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                              CommandName="Update" TabIndex="5" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                          &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                              CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                              CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Smpl_ID" SortExpression="Smpl_ID">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="grdFruit_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Smpl_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Smpl_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Size" SortExpression="Size">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="grdSize" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Size", "{0}") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Size") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Grade" SortExpression="Grade">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="grdddlGrade" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                              SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Grade") %>' TabIndex="1" AutoPostBack="True">
                              <asp:ListItem Value="">(Select)</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="AA">AA</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="A">A</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="B">B</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="C">C</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="F">F</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="UF">UF</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="USXF">USXF</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="USXFB">USXFB</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="USXFP">USXFP</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="USXFR">USXFR</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="CULL">CULL</asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:DropDownList>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Grade") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Color_Score" SortExpression="Color_Score">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="grdColor" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                              DataSourceID="color" DataTextField="score" DataValueField="rec_id" 
                              SelectedValue='<%# Bind("color") %>' TabIndex="2">
                              <asp:ListItem Value="0">(Select)</asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:DropDownList>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Color_Score") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bkgrd" SortExpression="Bkgrd">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="grdbkgrd" runat="server" 
                              SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Bkgrd") %>' TabIndex="3">
                              <asp:ListItem Value="">(Select)</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Value="Green">Green</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Value="Green/Yellow">Green/Yellow</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Value="Yellow/Cream">Yellow/Cream</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Value="Cream">Cream</asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:DropDownList>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Bkgrd") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Starch" SortExpression="Starch">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="grdStarch" runat="server" 
                              SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Starch", "{0:N}") %>' TabIndex="4">
                              <asp:ListItem Value="">(Select)</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="0.0">0.0</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="1.0">1.0</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="1.5">1.5</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="1.8">1.8</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="2.0">2.0</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="2.2">2.2</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="2.5">2.5</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="3.0">3.0</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="3.5">3.5</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="4.0">4.0</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="4.5">4.5</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="5.0">5.0</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="5.0">5.5</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="6.0">6.0</asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:DropDownList>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Starch") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="def_id_1" HeaderText="def_id_1" 
                      SortExpression="def_id_1" Visible="False" />
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Def_1" SortExpression="Def_1">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="grdddldef1" runat="server" 
                              SelectedValue='<%# Bind("def_id_1") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                              AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="defects" DataTextField="description" 
                              DataValueField="defect_id">
                              <asp:ListItem Value="0">(Select)</asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:DropDownList>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Def_1") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="def_id_2" HeaderText="def_id_2" 
                      SortExpression="def_id_2" Visible="False" />
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Def_2" SortExpression="Def_2">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="grdDefid2" runat="server" DataSourceID="defects" 
                              DataTextField="description" DataValueField="defect_id" 
                              SelectedValue='<%# Bind("def_id_2") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                              <asp:ListItem Value="0">(Select)</asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:DropDownList>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Def_2") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="color" HeaderText="color" SortExpression="color" 
                      Visible="False" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="app_def_id_1" HeaderText="app_def_id_1" 
                      SortExpression="app_def_id_1" Visible="False" />
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="App_1" SortExpression="App_1">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="grdddlapp1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                              DataSourceID="app_defect" DataTextField="description" 
                              DataValueField="defect_id" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("app_def_id_1") %>'>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="0">(Select)</asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:DropDownList>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("App_1") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate_1" SortExpression="Rate_1">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="grdRate1" runat="server" 
                              SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Rate_1") %>'>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="">(Select)</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>Initial</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>Moderate</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>Severe</asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:DropDownList>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Rate_1") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="app_def_id_2" HeaderText="app_def_id_2" 
                      SortExpression="app_def_id_2" Visible="False" />
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="App_2" SortExpression="App_2">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="grdddlapp2" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                              DataSourceID="app_defect" DataTextField="description" 
                              DataValueField="defect_id" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("app_def_id_2") %>'>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="0">(Select)</asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:DropDownList>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("App_2") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate_2" SortExpression="Rate_2">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="grdapprate2" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                              SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Rate_2") %>'>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="">(Select)</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="Initial">Initial</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="Moderate">Moderate</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Value="Severe">Severe</asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:DropDownList>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Rate_2") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WC" SortExpression="WC">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="grdWC" runat="server" 
                              SelectedValue='<%# Bind("WC") %>'>
                              <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>

                          </asp:DropDownList>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("WC") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IB" SortExpression="IB">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="grdIB" runat="server" 
                              SelectedValue='<%# Bind("IB") %>'>
                              <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>

                          </asp:DropDownList>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IB") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="qc_id" SortExpression="qc_id" Visible="False">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("qc_id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("qc_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
              </Columns>
              <EditRowStyle BackColor="#99CCFF" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
              <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
              <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
          </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="upper_level_grid" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AADConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="
select 
convert(varchar,qcm.qc_date,101) as 'Date',
map.storage as 'Storage',
var.description as 'Variety',
map.room as 'Room' ,
grw.grower_id+' - '+grw.grower_name as 'Grower'
from t_ap_qc_master qcm
inner join t_bin_master_ap map on map.master_ticket_id = qcm.master_ticket_id
inner join t_variety var on var.variety_id = map.variety_id
inner join t_grower grw on grw.grower_id = map.grower_id

where qcm.qc_id = @qc_id ">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="listQcId" Name="qc_id" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="fruit_id" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AADConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select top (1) fruit_id as 'Fruit ID'
from t_ap_qc_detail
where qc_id = @qc_id and grade is null ">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="listQcId" Name="qc_id" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>



                       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="fill_size" runat="server" 
                           ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AADConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT
 top (1)
qcd.size_name 
FROM t_ap_qc_master_fta qcf
inner JOIN t_ap_qc_detail qcd ON qcf.qc_id = qcd.qc_id and qcf.fruit_id = qcd.fruit_id
WHERE qcf.qc_id = @qc_id and qcd.grade is null ">
                           <SelectParameters>
                               <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="listQcId" Name="qc_id" 
                                   PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                           </SelectParameters>
                       </asp:SqlDataSource>

                         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="color" runat="server" 
                             ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AADConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT rec_id, score FROM t_ap_qc_color_score
WHERE score_id = 
(CASE WHEN ((SELECT variety_id FROM t_bin_master_ap
            WHERE master_ticket_id = (select master_ticket_id from t_ap_qc_master 
            WHERE qc_id = @qc_id)) IN ('09','1J','1P','4E','4F','4I'))
    THEN '2'
    WHEN ((SELECT variety_id FROM t_bin_master_ap
          WHERE master_ticket_id = (select master_ticket_id from t_ap_qc_master 
            WHERE qc_id = @qc_id)) IN ('6X','6Z'))
    THEN '3'
    ELSE '1' 
END)
and type = 'Coverage' and status = 'A'">
                             <SelectParameters>
                                 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="listQcId" Name="qc_id" 
                                     PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                             </SelectParameters>
                         </asp:SqlDataSource>


                         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="defects" runat="server" 
                             ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AADConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select defect_id, description
from t_defect where 
/*type = 'DEFECT' and */
inv_cat = 'AP' and status = 'A'
and defect_id IN ('41','11','42','36',
'19','187','186','26','46','20','10','40',
'1','224','89','83','3','14','37','212',
'213','191','2','38','83','226','230','232')
order by description"></asp:SqlDataSource>


                         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                             ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AADConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select defect_id, description
from t_defect where 
/*type = 'DEFECT' and */
inv_cat = 'AP' and status = 'A'
and defect_id IN ('41','11','42','36',
'19','187','186','26','46','20','10','40',
'1','224','89','83','3','14','37','212',
'213','191','2','38','83','226','230','232')
order by description"></asp:SqlDataSource>






                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="app_defect" runat="server" 
                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AADConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select defect_id, description
from t_defect 
where inv_cat = 'AP' and status = 'A'
and defect_id IN ('15','79','80','77','88','4','39')
order by description"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="app_defect0" runat="server" 
                             ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AADConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select defect_id, description
from t_defect 
where inv_cat = 'AP' and status = 'A'
and defect_id IN ('15','79','80','77','88','4','39')
order by description"></asp:SqlDataSource>


                         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="update" runat="server" 
                             ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AADConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="Select 
fruit_id 
from t_ap_qc_detail
where qc_id = @qc_id
and starch is not null">
                             <SelectParameters>
                                 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="listQcId" Name="qc_id" 
                                     PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                             </SelectParameters>
                         </asp:SqlDataSource>

      <% // Lables as description %>


<asp:Label id="lblQcID" style="Z-INDEX: 159; LEFT: 5px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 5px; HEIGHT: 24px; " 
        runat="server" Font-Names="Calibri">Select QC-ID:</asp:Label>





    <% // Text Boxes %> 
<% // Buttons%><% // Data Grids %>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="progress" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AADConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT
convert(int,qcd.fruit_id) as Smpl_ID,
qcd.size_name as Size,
qcd.grade as Grade,
cs.score as 'Color_Score',
qcd.background as 'Bkgrd',
convert(varchar,convert(decimal(15,1),qcd.starch)) as Starch,
isnull(qcd.def_id_1,'0') as def_id_1,
def1.description as 'Def_1',
isnull(qcd.def_id_2,'0') as def_id_2,
def2.description as Def_2,
isnull(qcd.color,'0') as color,
isnull(qcd.app_def_id_1,'0') as app_def_id_1,
def3.description as App_1,
qcd.app_rating_1 as Rate_1,
isnull(qcd.app_def_id_2,'0') as app_def_id_2,
def4.description as App_2,
qcd.app_rating_2 as Rate_2,
--qcf.color,
isnull(qcd.watercore,'0') as WC,
isnull(qcd.internal_browning,'0') as IB,
qcd.qc_id as qc_id
--qcd.status
FROM t_ap_qc_master_fta qcf
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_ap_qc_master qcm (NOLOCK) on qcm.qc_id = qcf.qc_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_ap_qc_detail qcd ON qcf.qc_id = qcd.qc_id and qcf.fruit_id = qcd.fruit_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_defect def1 ON def1.defect_id = qcd.def_id_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_defect def2 ON def2.defect_id = qcd.def_id_2
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_defect def3 ON def3.defect_id = qcd.app_def_id_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_defect def4 ON def4.defect_id = qcd.app_def_id_2
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_ap_qc_color_score cs (NOLOCK) on cs.rec_id = qcd.color
WHERE qcd.qc_id = @qc_id
ORDER BY qcd.fruit_id"
         UpdateCommand="update  t_ap_qc_detail 
set 
fruit_id = @Smpl_ID,
size_name = @Size,
[grade] = @Grade,
[def_id_1] = @def_id_1,
def_id_2 = @def_id_2,
app_def_id_1= @app_def_id_1,
app_rating_1 = @Rate_1,
app_def_id_2 = @app_def_id_2,
app_rating_2 = @Rate_2,
color = @color,
background = @Bkgrd,
watercore = @WC,
internal_browning = @IB,
starch = @Starch
where qc_id = @qc_id and fruit_id = @Smpl_ID" > 

        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="listQcId" Name="qc_id" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>

        <UpdateParameters>

            <asp:Parameter Name="Smpl_ID" Type="Int16"/>

        <asp:Parameter Name="Size" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Grade" Type="String"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="def_id_1" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="def_id_2" Type="Int32"  />
            <asp:Parameter Name="app_def_id_1" Type="Int32"  />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Rate_1" Type="String"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="app_def_id_2" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Rate_2" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="color" Type="Int32"  />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Bkgrd" type="String"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="WC" Type="String"  />
            <asp:Parameter Name="IB" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Starch" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="qc_id" Type="Int16" />
<asp:Parameter Name="Fruit_ID"></asp:Parameter>
        </UpdateParameters> 



    </asp:SqlDataSource>




</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this with jQuery. I can show you, but you need to post your markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with jQuery. Here is a generic way to do it, but if you post your markup I can customize it for you. I do this with all my .NET applications anyway just because of the general problems there are with using one form tag:

```
function initEnterKeyManagement() {
    //Remove Enter keys on all
    jQuery('input').keypress(function (e) {
        var code = null;
        code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        return (code == 13) ? false : true;
    });

    var oCurrForm = jQuery('#container with fields');
    var oCurrButton = oCurrForm.find('#button you want to trigger');

    //Submit Buttons
    if (oCurrButton && oCurrButton.length) {
        //Each field
        jQuery.each(oCurrForm.find('input'), function () {
            jQuery(this).keypress(function (e) {
                var code = null;
                code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if (code == 13)
                    oCurrButton.trigger('click');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Basically you're removing the default effect of the enter key, and then you're reassigning it to do the operation you want. In the case above, click().

Comment: Thank you Lawrence!! I did the whole thing in the designer. I have no c# code behind. Do you want to the see the markup for the whole gridview?

Comment: Where you have 'input' is that where the name of the button goes? Do place this code in the ascx.cs or the ascx page?

Comment: You'll want to put it in a Javascript function that loads on page ready. Your situation will be slightly more complicated because you'll need to iterate through each row. In the code above, where it says 'input' that is it going through each textbox within the container. If you post your markup in your question, I can customize it for you.